# LoginManager does not contain a definition for getInstance

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, xamarin, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to set permissions for Facebook login like so:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(signInActivity, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
```

However, i get this inline error: `'LoginManager' does not contain a definition for 'getInstance'`

Am i missing a reference or something?

Comment: LoginManager class is your own class? If yes you know better if it has that method or not? If it's not your class then it surely does not have that method. Did you copy this code from somewhere? If its c# then you might want to check if class has `Instance` property instead of `getInstance` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `LoginManager.Instance`.  In Xamarin, most Java `getXYZ()` methods are renamed as more C# like `XYZ` properties.